# How to tell community.aws.elb_application_lb to leave untouched the DefaultActions of specific listener

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

Ansible version: 2.9.16

I have several application load balancers in the AWS account and I'm trying to add a new rule to certain listeners from these load balancers. I'm using the `community.aws.elb_application_lb_info` plugin to gather information about the load balancers and locate the target listeners where to add the new rule.

In the json returned by `community.aws.elb_application_lb_info` the default actions of some listeners look like this:

```json
"default_actions":[
                  {
                     "target_group_arn":"some-arn",
                     "type":"forward",
                     "order":1,
                     "forward_config":{
                        "target_group_stickiness_config":{
                           "enabled":false
                        },
                        "target_groups":[
                           {
                              "target_group_arn":"some-arn",
                              "weight":1
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               ]
```

while others look like this:

```json
"default_actions":[
                  {
                     "redirect_config":{
                        "host":"some-host",
                        "protocol":"HTTPS",
                        "path":"/",
                        "status_code":"HTTP_302",
                        "query":"",
                        "port":"443"
                     },
                     "type":"redirect",
                     "order":1
                  }
               ]
```

Then I'm using `community.aws.elb_application_lb` plugin to add the rule to the listener.

Now the problem: the parameter `listeners: - DefaultActions` is mandatory in `community.aws.elb_application_lb`. I'm trying to specify it by extracting it from the json generated by `community.aws.elb_application_lb_info`, so my code looks like this:

```yaml
# load_balancer_name var is defined somewhere else
- name: "Gather information about the following ALB: {{ load_balancer_name }}"
  community.aws.elb_application_lb_info:
    ...
    names: "{{ load_balancer_name }}"
  register: elb_application_lb_info_ret

...

- name: Get the HTTPS:443 listener from ALB
  vars:
    listener_port: 443
    listener_protocol: "HTTPS"
  set_fact:
    listener: "{{ elb_application_lb_info_ret.load_balancers[0].listeners | selectattr('protocol', 'equalto', listener_protocol) | selectattr('port', 'equalto', listener_port) | list | first }}"

...
  
- name: Create the listener rule in the load balancer
  community.aws.elb_application_lb:
    name: "{{ load_balancer_name }}"
    .....
    listeners:
      - Protocol: "{{ listener.protocol }}"
        Port: "{{ listener.port }}"
        ....
        DefaultActions: "{{ listener.default_actions[0] }}"
        Rules:
          - Conditions:
              ....
```

but I get the following error:

```sh
TASK [xxx : Create the listener rule in the load balancer] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [xxx]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false
}

MSG:

argument DefaultActions is of type <class 'dict'> found in 'listeners'. and we were unable to convert to list: <class 'dict'> cannot be converted to a list
```

If in the playbook above I change `DefaultActions: "{{ listener.default_actions[0] }}"` to `DefaultActions: "{{ listener.default_actions }}"` I get the following error:

```sh
TASK [xxx : Create the listener rule in the load balancer] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: KeyError: 'Type'
fatal: [xxx]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "rc": 1
}

MSG:

MODULE FAILURE
See stdout/stderr for the exact error


MODULE_STDERR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
KeyError: 'Type'

So, looks like my approach is not good.
```

Is there any possibility to just tell `community.aws.elb_application_lb` to use the already defined DefaultActions for a listener to which I want to add a rule? All my load balancers already exist and have default actions defined. So I just want my script to add a rule and keep the default actions exactly as they are defined.

I guess it is possible to extract the data for each default action from json and recreate the default action each time, but the code would get pretty complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up re-creating DefaultActions. Not a nice solution but I couldn't come up with something better so far. But at least it works.

```yaml
# code to get the target 'listener' via the community.aws.elb_application_lb_info plugin

... 

# there are two types of default actions: redirect or forward
- name: Check if default action of listener is "redirect"
  vars:
    default_action: "{{ listener.default_actions[0] }}"
  when: default_action.type == 'redirect'
  set_fact:
    default_actions:
      - Type: "redirect"
        RedirectConfig:
          Protocol: "{{ default_action.redirect_config.protocol }}"
          Port: "{{ default_action.redirect_config.port }}"
          Host: "{{ default_action.redirect_config.host }}"
          Path: "{{ default_action.redirect_config.path }}"
          Query: "{{ default_action.redirect_config.query }}"
          StatusCode: "{{ default_action.redirect_config.status_code }}"

- name: Check if default action of listener is "forward"
  vars:
    default_action: "{{ listener.default_actions[0] }}"
  when: default_action.type == 'forward'
  set_fact:
    default_actions:
      - Type: "forward"
        TargetGroupArn: "{{ default_action.target_group_arn }}"
  
- name: Create/modify the listener rule in the load balancer
  community.aws.elb_application_lb:
    ...
    listeners:
      - Protocol: "{{ listener.protocol }}"
        ...
        DefaultActions: "{{ default_actions }}"
        Rules:
          ...
```